# Fetch API Django

Tags: json, django, api

I'm attempting to implement API from rapidapi.com

```
def home(request):

headers = {
'x-rapidapi-host': "...",
'x-rapidapi-key': "..."
}

url = "..."
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
```

my print statement shows the following:

```
{'data': [{'iso': 'CHN', 'name': 'China'}, {'iso': 'TWN', 'name': 'Taipei and environs'}, {'iso': 'USA', 'name': 'US'}, {'iso': 'JPN', 'name': 'Japan'}, {'iso': 'THA', 'name': 'Thailand'}, {'iso': 'KOR', 'name': 'Korea, South'}, {'iso': 'SGP', 'name': 'Singapore'}, {'iso': 'PHL', 'name': 'Philippines'}, {'iso': 'MYS', 'name': 'Malaysia'}, {'iso': 'VNM', 'name': 'Vietnam'}, {'iso': 'AUS', 'name': 'Australia'}, {'iso': 'MEX', 'name': 'Mexico'}, {'iso': 'BRA', 'name': 'Brazil'}, {'iso': 'COL', 'name': 'Colombia'}, {'iso': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'}
```

How do I insert the data in my template ???

I do understand it's a list ...

I did attempted in my views.py :

```
 d ={
    "iso":response ['data']['iso'],
    "name":response ['data']['name']
    }
```

my template looks like so:

```
    <h1> {{data.iso}}</h1>
    <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
```

It does not work ...

Comment: Can you share where you pass `d`, the context, to `render`? Your keys appear to be "iso" and "name": `<h1>{{ iso }}</h1>`

Comment: yes in the context

Comment: Does using `{{ iso }}` and `{{ name }}` instead of `{{ data.iso }}` and `{{ data.name }}` in your template work?

Comment: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error

Answer (score 0):

```
# d ={
# "c":r ['data'][31]
# }
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries